# Dapper Query Return Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I'm working on MVC Web API with Dapper version 1.38.0.0. I write this code

```
 var param = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("Select Top @count * From tblCourse", @"(?<!\w)@\w+"))
 {
     string key = match.Value;
     string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[key.Replace("@", null)];
     param.Add(key, value);
 }

 result = con.Query<dynamic>("Select Top @count * From tblCourse", param);
```

But I have an error on result's row.

```
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@count'.
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `param` at the moment of `con.Query` execution?

Comment: An int32 value, example 5

Comment: That's a kinda scary way of auto-parameterizing query-string arguments into SQL. Just sayin'. It'll probably work, but... yikes. I wonder if it could be abused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TOP @param
```

Is not legal in SQL server. 2 options:

```
Select Top (@count) * From tblCourse
```

Or

```
Select Top {=count} * From tblCourse
```

The first is SQL-server's way of representing this. The second is a dapper-specific feature that injects integer values (only: it doesn't work for strings) directly into the query. If the value is usually the same, the second will usually perform better. Of course, with the second you'd need a different regex too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`result = con.Query<dynamic>("Select Top (@count) * From tblCourse", param);`

`Top` needs to be inside parenthesis when it's value is supplied via a parameter